# How should I modify a variable across Python3 coroutines?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm attempting to write a script for CI automation. The script should:

1. Start a server
2. Forward each line to stdout or stderr, as we see it
3. Search stdout for messages indicating success or failure
4. Kill the server
5. Exit with an exit code based on the messages we saw

To forward each line and parse `stdin`, I'm using an `asyncio` coroutine. This coroutine sets class member variables, and then sets a condition variable to signal the main thread when we're done.

This script does run correctly, but it is not type-safe. Pylance types `self.success` as `Never` after I `assert self.success is not None`. This is because Pylance doesn't expect another thread to change `self.success` into a bool out from under us. I don't blame Pylance for this! I just don't know the idiomatic, type-safe way to get a value out of a coroutine, unless the coroutine returns the value.

```py
import asyncio
import os
import re
import signal
import sys
import typing


TIMEOUT_SEC = 60 * 10

PID_REGEX = re.compile(r".*\[pid: (\d+)\].*")


class ServerRunner:
    success: typing.Optional[bool]
    server_pid: typing.Optional[int]
    finished_parsing: asyncio.Event

    async def run_backend_dev_server(self) -> typing.NoReturn:
        self.success = None
        self.finished_parsing = asyncio.Event()
        self.server_pid = None

        process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
            "bazel",
            "run",
            "//backend:dev-server",
            stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        )

        await asyncio.wait(
            [
                asyncio.create_task(self.parse_stdout(process.stdout)),
                asyncio.create_task(self.forward_stderr(process.stderr)),
                asyncio.create_task(self.finished_parsing.wait()),
            ],
            timeout=TIMEOUT_SEC,
            return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED,
        )

        assert self.success is not None
        if self.success:
            print("Backend server successfully started.")
        else:
            print("Backend server failed to start.")

        assert self.server_pid is not None
        print(f"Killing process {self.server_pid}")
        os.kill(self.server_pid, signal.SIGTERM)

        print(f"Shutting process down (PID {process.pid})...")
        # process.terminate()
        await process.wait()

        if self.success:
            sys.exit(0)
        else:
            sys.exit(1)

    async def parse_stdout(self, stdout: asyncio.StreamReader) -> None:
        """Process the given stream and look for signs of success or failure.

        Return True if we see a line indicating successful startup.
        Return False if we see an error message.

        """
        while not stdout.at_eof():
            # Forward to stdout
            line = await stdout.readline()
            line = line.decode()
            sys.stdout.write(line)
            sys.stdout.flush()

            if self.finished_parsing.is_set():
                continue

            # Look for messages which indicate success or failure
            if self.success is None:
                if "RETOOL DEBUG SERVER started and listening" in line:
                    self.success = True
                elif "Error starting main backend" in line:
                    self.success = False
                elif "Jobs container crashed" in line:
                    self.success = False

            # Look for the server's process ID in the stdout messages
            if self.server_pid is None:
                pid_regex_match = PID_REGEX.match(line)
                if pid_regex_match is not None:
                    self.server_pid = int(pid_regex_match.group(1))

            if self.success is not None and self.server_pid is not None:
                self.finished_parsing.set()

    async def forward_stderr(
        self,
        stderr: asyncio.StreamReader,
    ) -> None:
        """Forward a subprocess stream to one of our output streams."""
        while not stderr.at_eof():
            line = await stderr.readline()
            line = line.decode()
            sys.stderr.write(line)
            sys.stderr.flush()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(ServerRunner().run_backend_dev_server())
```